# How to use different Java versions for different applications without changing the Java bin directory in path variable?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have one RCP application and some other Java applications with different requirements on JVM version on the client desktop to be able to work.

One is 1.7 and two are 1.6, 1.5 requirements.
Depending on the Java binary directory order in the path variable, the Java version is selected (assume 1.7). So one application (which requires 1.7) is working and others are not.

Is there a way to ensure that all three will work?

or

Is there any approach that we can define a particular application should use a particular version by default independent of the Java bin directory of the path variable?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an environment variable `Java_Home`, you basically tell the location where java executable is located and thus on executing java command, system can find it. What you can do is specify the full path to java.exe in a command and application will be executed using that Java executable version.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has the concept of *Execution environments* and a means to assign JVM installation locations to certain execution environments.

Got to the preferences dialog (main menu > *Window* > *Preferences*) and register all that JRE and JDK installations that are needed under *Java* > *Installed JREs*.

Now you can them to the respective execution environments under *Java* > *Installed JREs* > *Execution Environments*.

After these settings are made, you can specify the desired execution environment for each Java project in your workspace. For Eclipse plug-in projects, open the MANIFEST.MF and choose the execution environment(s) on the *Overview* page. This change with update your build path accordingly.

For plain Java projects, you can change the execution environment under *Project Properties* > *Java Build Path* > *Libraries*.

You may need to adjust existing launch configurations to use the 'project execution environment'. For launch configurations of type *Eclipse Application*, the setting can be changed on the *Main* page.

Comment: In eclipse we can change the version. but I want in end state, means when I am clicking on my application.exe file it should use 1.7 independent of path variable. Can we do any changes in ".ini" file to select a particular version?

Comment: You can bundle the necessary JRE together with your RCP product. Depending on how your product is built, either in the product configuration (page _Lauching_ > _Execution Environment_ > Bundle JRE for this environment with the product) or in your Tycho build: http://eclipseo.blogspot.de/2014/11/bundle-jre-along-with-your-product.html

Answer (score 0):

Approach:

You can detect the java version by command `java -version` and parse it to get version information. now you can have check or block with popup message while invoking the application and inform you do not have compatible java, please go there and do this kind of something.

better you can have a drop down initially which have all java version information installed and on the basis of selection you can have above mentioned approach.